# NSURLSession request fails when call from iOS 8.3 It work perfectly in iOS 12

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, ios8.1

I am using an https URL and project deployment target is 8.1 I am using Xcode 10.2 to build the app. My app works perfectly in ios 12, But when I run the app in ios 8.1 service call fails. I am not getting any errors in the message. I have tried with challenge delegate methods with NSURLSession. I have added different security disabling method to info.plist But still not working.

Comment: Have you tried turning on logging at the CFNetwork level?  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/debugging_https_problems_with_cfnetwork_diagnostic_logging?language=objc

Comment: I really thank you for your reply. I will check with it.

Comment: Just a quick hint: 99% of the time, what causes problems when working with those delegate methods is the app doing some sort of `if (protectionSpace == ...)` and then forgetting to include an `else` clause that requests default handling via the callback.  Make absolutely sure that every path through your code results in the callback getting called (if not immediately, then eventually).